# Getting my AJAX error message to display

Tags: php, ajax, email, message

I have a success message that is displayed no matter if the user data is valid or not. I have an error message but I'm having trouble getting it to display. I'm not the best coder so be nice :)

Also, for some reason when I receive an email via the form the user's email comes up as user@MISSING_DOMAIN. My first issue takes priority, so you don't have to help me with this one if its too much.

Form Code

```
<form action="contactformprocess3.php" method="post" class="myForm" >
<input name="name" type="text" id="f1" class="name-textinput"/><br />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var f1 = new LiveValidation('f1');
        f1.add( Validate.Presence );
    </script>

<input name="email" type="text" id="f21" class="email-textinput"/><br />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var f21 = new LiveValidation('f21');
            f21.add( Validate.Presence );
            f21.add( Validate.Email );
            f21.add( Validate.Length, { minimum: 10, maximum: 35 } );
    </script>

<textarea name="message" rows="9" cols="34" id="field3" class="message-textinput"></textarea>
    <span class="underform">
        <input type="reset" class="reset" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" class="submit" />
    </span>
</form>
```

AJAX

```
$(function() {
$('.myForm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    var post_url = form.attr('action');
    var post_data = form.serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: post_url,
        data: post_data,
        success: function(msg) {
            $('.success-box').fadeIn("slow").delay(3000).fadeOut("slow");
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error, req) {
            $('.failure-box').fadein("slow").delay(3000).fadeOut("slow");
        }

    });
  });
});
```

PHP EMAIL

```
<?php
$to = 'wj@pieceofmedesigns.com';
$subject = 'Piece of Me Designs';
$from = $_POST['email'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

if (mail($to, $subject, $message, 'From: '.$name.' &lt;'.$from.'&gt;')) {
    echo 'Message was sent successfully.';
} else {
    echo 'There was a problem sending your message.';
}
```

?>

Answer (score 2):

What said Ed is totally correct. It means that you are waiting in the "error:" part of the ajax block what is for you a business rule disfunction (email not sent), while only technical errors will show up in this block.

A business error still returns "success" regarding to the technical point of view; it is just a different "success" answer that your application has to handle.

So, basically for you the solution is to check the echo:

```
success: function(msg) {
    if (msg == 'Message was sent successfully.') {
       $('.success-box').fadeIn("slow").delay(3000).fadeOut("slow");
    } else {
       $('.failure-box').fadein("slow").delay(3000).fadeOut("slow");
    }
},
error: function(xhr, status, error, req) {
    //alert the user there was a technical problem
}
```

I may recommend you return XML based echos from your php services, then you could manage tags and normalized responses way easier.

Answer (score 1):

The AJAX error condition occurs when it is not possible to either contact the server or the server returns a status code that is not 200. Such things are file not found, script errors or network problems,

So to get the correct message you need to validate the data. You can do this before using AJAX to ensure that the data you send to the servers script has been validated.

Also you need to get your PHP script to do validation. This is a good policy to ensure security.